Movie in which a small village discovers they're AI, not human
There's a movie I saw on either Netflix or Prime within the last year in which a small community in a somewhat arid climate, post-apocalypse desolation, are concerned about their regular shipment of supplies being delayed.  The main character (female) makes a trek to the supply depot and, while there, confirmed her suspicions that she's an android, and then discovers her entire village is a group of androids and the reason the supplies stopped arriving is because they don't need supplies.  They're androids, not humans.

If you saw it on prime or Netflix as recently as last year, it would be in your history, surely.

I think there was an episode of an anthology show along those lines. Maybe Black Mirror?

Slightly out of subject: You might be interested in the movie Extinction.

This is the "Autofac" episode of Electric Dreams on Netflix.
It contains the elements of the supplies stopping and the characters discovering they are androids.
Plot summary here.

+1 Interesting that Phil Dick's short story "Autofac" has no androids. The humans are humans. It's really frustrating they felt the need to change this, since the original story works quite well...

(In fact, the whole point of Autofac (short story) is that the Autofac won't let humans become self-sufficient because it fails the acknowledge the emergency has ended, hoards all resources, and forces humans to become dependent on it. In typical PKD's fashion, the ending is... not optimistic).

@AndresF. Agreed, I like the story, this was a disappointment.
